# How to write IsFirtRowAsColumnNames function in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I've seen a file in which there is a `IsFirtRowAsColumnNames` property in `C#` to read from an Excel file.

When I use it, I get an error message.

what should the reason be?

```
IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
reader.IsFirtRowAsColumnNames = true;
```

The error message is:

> 'ExcelDataReader.IExcelDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'IsFirstRowAsColumnNames' and no extension method 'IsFirstRowAsColumnNames' accepting a first argument of type 'ExcelDataReader.IExcelDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: share the exception message...

Comment: Maybe because it is correctly spelled `IsFirstRowAsColumnNames` (you're missing an `s` in the `First` ...)

Comment: Of course I was wrong here, but even after the correction there is an error message that he does not recognize it.

Comment: Please post the exception details/error message.

Comment: "'ExcelDataReader.IExcelDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'IsFirstRowAsColumnNames' and no extension method 'IsFirstRowAsColumnNames' accepting a first argument of type 'ExcelDataReader.IExcelDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 2):

Seems the property got dropped, see commented lines in this [sample](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/blob/407e0b4cead3744461fa8a88d2cdab2cba7fee96/src/TestApp/Form1.cs). You now can use [`DataSet`](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/tree/407e0b4cead3744461fa8a88d2cdab2cba7fee96) extension and configure it using `ExcelDataSetConfiguration` object to inform it that there are headers in first row:

```
using (var rdr = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs))
{
    var conf=new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
            UseHeaderRow = true //THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE AFTER
        }
    };

    var ds = rdr.AsDataSet(conf); //THIS IS WHERE IT IS USED
}
```

Also, if you wrap it in `using` statement (like in above sample) it will be better (to be concise).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue after i followed some indian guy on youtube.

had some issues from his video the `reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;`
so i did some research and came up with a solution that should work for most people that have had this issue.
so what you do is that you replace the "IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;" part with

```
 reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
{
   ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
   {
      UseHeaderRow = true
   }
});
```

this should allow it to work, this is because the newer ExcelDataReader does not use IsFirstRowAsColumnNames anymore so you have to replace it.
Also if you are using a xlsx file instead of a xls file you have to change any filter you have to .xlsx for it to work, cause that caused me a headache.